# What "damage" is Tom Riddle referring to?

Tags: harry-potter

Tom Riddle says to Harry Potter, who was bitten by snake:

> Tom Riddle: I'd guess you have little more than a minute to live.
> You'll be with your dear Mudblood mother soon, Harry. Funny, **the
> damage** a silly little book can do...especially in the hands of a silly
> little girl.

What "damage" is Tom Riddle referring to?

Comment: dead chickens, petrified students, petrified ghost, a nearly dead Ginny and soon to be dead Harry...all because of a silly little book in the hands of a silly little girl

Comment: Looks like an answer, @NKCampbell.  Should be one, not a comment.

Comment: This post seems to be very negatively received.  I'm not sure why...

Comment: @Anonymous there are a few users who generally don’t like these types of questions where they’re more language explanation than much else. Or where the answer can be viewed as obvious.

Comment: Curious: Are you asking for the meaning of the idiom *funny the damage X can do* or do you understand the idiom and are asking simply because you have not done any prior research? It would be helpful if we understood how much you already know about the topic and what you've already found out on your own. People don't like questions where it's obvious the querent hasn't done their homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @NKCampbell said in his comment, the book, by being in the hands of Ginny and thus controlling her as the book was a Horcrux, did the following damages:

- **Dead chickens**: as chickens are Basilisk's mortal enemy, she was ordered by the book to kill them so it can roam free in the school.
- **Petrified students and ghost**: several students looked indirectly at the Basilisk in its eyes and were then petrified instead of killed. On the other hand, Sir Nicholas looked directly at the Basilisk's eyes but as he is a ghost, he couldn't be killed again, so he was just "petrified".
- **Students nearly killed**: two students were nearly killed, Ginny and Harry. Ginny was pouring her heart and her thoughts inside the book and Voldemort's part living inside the Horcrux was growing stronger because of that and almost killed her by taking her vital energy to become "alive" again. Harry was almost killed by the Basilisk when he went to save Ginny in the Chamber of Secrets.

Even though this book was only one of the seven Voldemort's Horcruxes, it did, in the end, quite a lot of damages.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that the answer would be..

- Chickens being murdered
- Petrifications (and killings from past attacks
- Ginny nearly dead, barely able to stand, much less breathe
- Harry nearly dead, with the Basilisk fang

This  has all been said by @NKcampbell, so boom.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please note that this answer has already been elaborated upon above, and you shouldn't post duplicate answers.  You should probably read [answer].

Answer (score 0):

I think it does not only mean about the dead chickens or about the students, but this line has a deeper meaning. Tom Riddle is also known as Voldemort, and so if his plan would be successfully completed, Harry and Ginny would have died, the mudbloods
would die too, and the Basilisk could kill every Muggle born or every enemy of Slytherin's heir. Voldemort would have also win the war, and he would be the ruler of the wizarding world himself. Fortunately, there are many brave students, such as Harry, Ron and Hermione, so Tom's plan didn't totally complete.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Are you trying to say that "damage" includes potential future harms as well as what has already happened?